# SSRS single datasource impact

Tags: reporting-services

In my client environment there are many SSRS reports have been deployed. Each having separate data source and it is pointing same server and same database.
Is it good that to convert into single data source based on the database base. Will there be any performance issue or any other issue will occur? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Manageability then please go with a shared data source.

As far i'm aware, there won't be any performance issues.

When you create a shared data source, all of the connection information for the data source you’re connecting to is stored outside of the report, and deployed as its own object. Other reports are able to reference the shared data source.

On whether its good to convert into single data source based on the database base, i would say it depends, but in general I tend to use the following guidelines.

1. If I have multiple reports that are going to be referencing the same data source, a shared data source makes perfect sense
2. If I have a data source that I know is only going to be used by one report, and never by any others, then an embedded data source might make more sense, although this is kind of a rare case in my experience. If you do created an embedded data source and start getting requests for other reports using the same data source…you should definitely convert it to a shared data source.

The advantage of using shared data sources starts to become evident once you start to have a large number of reports to manage. If you have to point your reports to different environments like dev / QC / Stg / prod, you can change all the reports at once by simply changing the information in the shared data source. Had you created all your reports with embedded data sources however, you’d have to edit each report individually, and if you have a lot of reports, that can translate into a lot of work.